# Retrieving what did work when Task.WhenAll throws exception

Tags: c#, asynchronous

Consider

```
string[] pages;
Task [] asyncOps = 
    (from url in urls select DownloadStringAsync(url)).ToArray();
try
{
    pages = await Task.WhenAll(asyncOps);
    ...
}
catch(Exception exc)
{
    foreach(Task<string> faulted in asyncOps.Where(t => t.IsFaulted))
    {
        … // work with faulted and faulted.Exception
    }
}
```

from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873173%28v=vs.110%29.aspx. How can I retrieve the pages that DID work?

Or better, how can I keep going and compute the rest of the pages?

Answer (score 4):

Instead of doing all the downloads and then handling each success/error separately, I think it's much cleaner if you define a separate "download and handle error" operation:

```
Task [] asyncOps = 
    (from url in urls select DownloadStringWithErrorCheckingAsync(url)).ToArray();
string[] pages = await Task.WhenAll(asyncOps);
var successfulPages = pages.Where(x => x != null);

...

private static Task<string> DownloadStringWithErrorCheckingAsync(string url)
{
  try
  {
    return await DownloadStringAsync(url);
  }
  catch(Exception exc)
  {
    ... // work with exc
    return null;
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I know this is a possible workaround. I was curious to see if there was a way to do it without adding an error handling function.

Comment: @tofutim: It doesn't matter if the class is sealed. You're just changing `DownloadStringAsync` to a more complex operation. I split it into a separate method for readability but you could do it just as easily with a lambda expression.

Comment: Yes, I think there is probably no way to do it any other way. I did notice that when the WhenAll fails the rest of the unfinished tasks get canceled.

Comment: I was trying to handle the Aggregated Exception after the WhenAll() with taskList[taskIndex].Status == TaskStatus.RanToCompletion; but one unhandled exception in the list of tasks was, for lack of better terms, preventing the flow of data from the successful tasks from being returned from the containing method. So, by using the "in-task" exception handling, I now just use the TaskStatus to warn if a task is not using exception handling.

Answer (score 1):

I've same problem. I need to start several task, wait for each to terminate and then, process all task Status/Exception/Result.

I can't use Stephen's solution because final processings are not independent from each other. It's some kind of: if task1 is Ok, I will try to take result of task2 and if not, I will take task3 result. I need each response to infer my behavior.

```
Task[] toWait = new Task[]{...};

await Task.WhenAll(toWait).ContinueWith((t) => {t?.Exception?.Handle((exc)=>true);}, ct);
```

I don't await result of WhenAll but result of ContinueWith whose action only silently handle exception.

It's not very elegant but we can hide it with a method like this one:

```
public static Task WhenAllNoThrow(this Task[] toWait, CancellationToken token)
{
    return TaskEx.WhenAll(toWait).ContinueWith((t) => { t?.Exception?.Handle((exc) => true); }, token);
}
```

EDIT: Added null-conditional Operators ?.

Answer (score 0):

Its not clear what "DownloadStringAsync" is, I assumed it was WebClient.DownloadStringAsync

This function does not return a task, you need to subscribe to a the complete event to capture the result.

It doesnt appear that is what you wanted to do so I changed your code to do a parallel for loop instead.

```
Dictionary<string, string> pages = new Dictionary<string, string>();
Dictionary<string, string> errors = new Dictionary<string, string>();
string[] urls = new string[] { "http://www.google.com", "http://www.bbc.co.uk" };

Parallel.ForEach<string>(urls, (url) =>
{
    var webClient = new System.Net.WebClient();

    try
    {
        pages[url] = webClient.DownloadString(new Uri(url));
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        errors[url] = ex.Message;
    }                
});

// The successful
foreach(var kvp in pages)
{
    Console.WriteLine(kvp.Key);
    //Console.WriteLine(kvp.Value);
}

// The failures
foreach (var kvp in errors)
{
    Console.WriteLine(kvp.Key);
    //Console.WriteLine(kvp.Value);
}
```

Comment: Assume it returns a Task. I want to use Task.WhenAll